# How to connect Perforce with Rider IDE

Tags: perforce, rider, unreal-engine5

I've set up a local Perforce server to store my Unreal engine project. I like to use Rider as my code editor and I'm having some trouble getting Rider to connect to my Perforce server as it displays in the top left "No Perforce Connections"  [No Perforce Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPzYU.png)

I went to Rider's settings for Perforce and entered the configuration parameters manually, clicked the test connection button and the connection was successful. However, whenever I make a change to a file it does not let me select which changlist to apply to and it still shows "No Perforce Connections" on the top left of the UI. I have also tried setting the config via environment variables but the test connection fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  [Rider Perforce settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8y1M.png) [no change lists
appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WrR7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Rider on macOS recently - the fix for me was to install the `p4` command line client, and use `p4 set` to ensure all the connection details are correct (even though you, like me, are overriding them in Rider's settings).

After that I restarted Rider and all was well!